# WIN32 opening a folder

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to open a folder from my code. I had previously written a visual basic program that did the job. Now I am trying to do this with C++ and WIN32 and not having any luck. Folder contains an address to a server. I tried CreateProcess and ShellExecute and they both cannot open the folder in the server. can you please help?

first method I tried

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "explore", "\\ftpg.tb.ch\\locations", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

second method I tried

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"));
LPTSTR pathfolder = _tcsdup(TEXT(" /e,/root,\\ftpg.tb.ch\\locations"));
CreateProcess( szCmdline, pathfolder, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );
```

this is the previously working visual studio VB code

```
Dim testst As String = "\\ftpg.tb.ch\locations"
Process.Start("explorer.exe", testst)
```

Comment: Perhaps `\\\\ftpg.tb.ch\\locations`

Comment: NTP, but: instead of calling `ZeroMemory` and assigning to `cb`, just do `PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { sizeof( pi ) };`.

Comment: Also NTP, but instead of `_tcsdup` and `TEXT` and other such support-of-Windows-9x monstrosities, and it's *guaranteed* that you won't be producing a Windows 9x-compatible executable, just use wide strings.

Comment: Also NTP, but as I recall one of the string arguments of `CreateProcess` needs to be mutable, it can be written to. So passing pointers to literals for both args is wrong. Check the documentation and e.g. use `std::wstring`.

Comment: Finally, in modern C++ you can use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Establishing a habit of using `nullptr` can be advantegous when e.g. calling some function that forwards arguments, where `NULL` might be forwarded as integral 0 instead of pointer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Although in general sound advice to use `nullptr` in C++, there is no benefit when talking to the Windows API. As a C interface there aren't any overloads or templates, where `nullptr` can make a difference. As for `CreateProcess`: It's the second argument that needs to point to writable memory, **when calling the wide character version**. The OP isn't, so there's no immediate problem (except for using ANSI encoding itself).

Comment: @IInspectable: You don't know which version the OP's code is calling, due to the silly `T` macros. The default setting for a visual C++ project is `UNICODE` defined.  Still, I think I overlooked the `_tcsdup` calls, probably because there's no freeing shown, i.e., misidentification of the error.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I guess I just assumed, that the `ShellExecute` and `CreateProcess` calls were used in the same project at different times. `ShellExecute` is using narrow character strings. Regardless, though, as you point out, there wouldn't be an issue either way, due to passing writable buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation from the VB is wrong and does not correctly escape your backslash characters. Instead of

```
"\\ftpg.tb.ch\\locations"
```

you must write

```
"\\\\ftpg.tb.ch\\locations"
```

As an aside, please use `ShellExecuteEx` rather than `ShellExecute`. The former provides proper error handling, the latter does not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `ShellExecuteEx` “provides proper error handling”, and how `ShellExecute` “does not”?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121018-00/?p=6303

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks! Useful.

Comment: @sanjaya Please click the accept button (the big grey check mark) on this answer because it seems that the answer was helpful to you. Thanks!